# How to setup cartridge applications replication between few Tarantool routers?

Tags: replication, tarantool, tarantool-cartridge

How to setup cartridge applications replication between few Tarantool routers on different phisical/virtual servers?

[image: tarantool configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as any other nodes - you should press `Join existing replicaset` instead of `Create new replicaset` when configuring a new router in admin UI.
If you' experiencing any particular issues, please specify them too.

BTW, the screenshot you posted, seems to contain the answer already.

Comment: I talk about cartridge app replication, not data.
when i do on server1 : 
cartridge build 
need make some command on server2 (+app source copy)

Comment: Catridge build/start is supposed to be run in dev environment. For bigger stands, you should consider `cartridge pack` to prepare an artifact of your app (e. g. rpm), and deploy them manually or use tools such as ansible. I suggest [this](https://github.com/tarantool/ansible-cartridge/tree/master/examples/getting-started-app) step-by-step guide for the process.